# How to set the Sheet names with static date?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to set the Sheet names with static **DATE** with Vba code. i.e, Name should not change tomorrow. Kindly help me on this.here is my code.

```
Sub MaterialRequest()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim SheeetName As String
    Dim i As Long

    SheeetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("Z3").Value
    Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Name = SheeetName & "ENGGMR" & i
    Next
End sub
```

By this code, next day, sheet name automatically changing.

Comment: Why you are looping through every worksheet and renaming them? Just use `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = SheeetName & "ENGGMR" & Worksheets.Count` instead of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should qualify `worksheets` with the workbook like `WB.Worksheets` to make sure that the correct workbook is being used.

And then you can directly rename the new worksheet with `WS.Name`

```
Sub MaterialRequest()
    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Dim newSheetDate As String
    Dim i As Long

    newSheetDate = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Range("Z3").Value)
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets.Add(after:=WB.Worksheets(WB.Worksheets.Count))
    WS.Name = newSheetDate & "ENGGMR" & WB.Worksheets.Count
End Sub
```

I also recommend to fully qualify the range in `Filename:=Range("Z3").Value` to a worksheet e.g. `Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("Z3").Value` to ensure the correct worksheet is being used.

Comment: Thank you.It helped

Comment: @Divya If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution, so other users can see that this question is solved.